# ssh connections to HP 5900 JC772A closed

Tags: hp-comware

I have a pair of switches that are not allowing us to ssh in reliably.

Occasionally we are authenticated but if we type a single character, the connection dies. We don't have IPMI consoles configured. When we attach a USB-serial cable, the console is flooded with duplicate IP address messages and I can't figure out how to disable them.

The software is probably version 7.1.045 Release 2311P05, because that's the version on all the other JC772A we have. The dudes who set up these switches have long since left the company and left no notes.

What other data would it be useful for me to post here?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full switch configurations.

Answer (score 6):

> the console is flooded with duplicate IP address messages and I can't figure out how to disable them

Fix your *duplicate IP* problem. The connect is closing because the other machine with the same IP is responding with a FIN/RST for the connection that doesn't belong to it.

Answer (score 5):

> When we attach a USB-serial cable, the console is flooded with duplicate IP address messages and I can't figure out how to disable them.

That's the likely cause of your problem with SSH: the switch's IP addresses is also used elsewhere, causing any network connection to the switch itself to die or to not work at all.

Simply run a packet capture, ARP analysis or the like to find the MAC address of the colliding node. Follow that MAC's port and the cable and you've got the culprit.

Alternatively, change the switch's IP address using the serial console.

You also might want to review your IP address management. Either there was a configuration error (which shouldn't happen) or someone neglected the addressing scheme altogether. Using strict DHCP with DHCP snooping and forced MAC-IP binding could be a solution for that.

Comment: Mistakes not happening seems a tough requirement for anyone, even more so in a case where someone has left long since with no notes...

Comment: Still, you need to repair those things. A strict, monitored addressing scheme can prevent more of that in the future. Also, make sure that there's sufficient documentation. A large, undocumented network is impossible to maintain (without redoing the documentation first).